# wordpress select a term range with get_terms()

Tags: wordpress, range, taxonomy

Is there a way to query a term range from a custom taxonomy using get_terms()? get like terms 1-10, 10-20? I am using a custom taxonomy to show a list of company names in a html table but now there are too many terms and it is making the site slow so I want to implement a pagination system. I am thinking now that using a taxonomy was a bad idea and I should have put the company names in a mysql table instead. The below is a short sample of what I have

```
    $emp_list_terms = get_terms('employers_list', array('hide_empty' => false));
            foreach ($emp_list_terms as $term) 
                $emp_id = intVal($term->description);
                $emp_data = get_user_meta($emp_id);
etc.. etc..
```

Comment: You're looking for `offset` - [See WordPress Forums Example](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-paginate-taxonomy-terms)

Answer (score 0):

```
$emp_list_terms = get_terms('employers_list', array('hide_empty' => false , 'number' => 10 ));
```

'number' defines the maximum number of records to return.